# How to get min value or desired value in given string when string is having slash in between

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a column which is having slash in between for example given below, where ever numbers are present in a string I need to get min value where ever their is number and alpha numeric then I need to get only alpha numeric. This has to be done in pysaprk dataframe.

Example input:

1. 111/112
2. 113/PAG
3. 801/802/803/804
4. 801/62S

Desired output should be

1. 111
2. PAG
3. 801
4. 62S

I have tried exploding the dataframe column but it doesn't work. please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **`array_min`** function by using **`split`** inbuilt function.

- `split` -> splits the string and create array
- `array_min` -> get minimum value from the array

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('111/112',),('113/PAG',),('801/802',),('801/62S',)],['ip'])
df.withColumn("ip",array_min(split(col("ip"),"/"))).show(10,False)
#+---+
#|ip |
#+---+
#|111|
#|113|
#|801|
#|62S|
#+---+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([('111/112',),('113/PAG/PAZ',),('801/802',),('801/62S',)],['ip'])
df.withColumn("temp_ip1", split(col("ip"),"/").cast("array<int>")).\
  withColumn("temp_ip2", split(col("ip"),"/")).\
  withColumn("temp", array_except(col("temp_ip2"),array_except(col("temp_ip1"),array(lit(None))).cast("array<string>"))).\
    withColumn("min_ip", array_min(when(size(col("temp"))>0,col("temp")).otherwise(col("temp_ip2")))).\
      drop(*['temp_ip1','temp_ip2','temp']).\
    show(10,False)

#+-----------+------+
#|ip         |min_ip|
#+-----------+------+
#|111/112    |111   |
#|113/PAG/PAZ|PAG   |
#|801/802    |801   |
#|801/62S    |62S   |
#+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In row number 2 I need to get PAG instead of min value. The problem is where ever their is only numbers then need to pick min value if their is combination of number and alpha  numeric then I need to get alphanumeric value which is PAG in my case.